# flowplayer $f returning object expected

Tags: jquery, asp.net, flowplayer

Im using flowplayer qith jquery to overlay a video , but the function $f is returning object expected, what am i doing wrong?
i have all my scripts right

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/flowplayer-3.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    .....
   var player = $f("player", "flowplayer-3.2.7.swf");
   alert(player); // this is returning object expected
```

Thanks alot

Comment: same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371404/flowplayer-f-returning-object-expected ?

Comment: yeah by mistake. i thought it didnt submit the question.. i deleted the second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but even with the error I'm having the overlay playing the media...
Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
<script> 

    // this simple call does the magic
    $(function() {
        $("a.flowplayer").flowembed("../FlowPlayerDark.swf",  {initialScale:'scale'});      
    });  

</script>
```

See installation examples here: http://www.eleg.hu/video/flowplayer/examples/